# Extract file path strings from a text file, to use in Windows CMD script

Tags: windows, file, cmd, path

I want to use a Windows CMD script to parse a text file and use any file path names that it finds to copy/delete files.

A sample from the text file where the file paths are located:

> "Target file: D:\root\TMC01_20170704042819.csv (101MB 04/07/2017)"

Using the above example, I need the script to populate any filenames found, to the create commands like below...

```
XCOPY "D:\root\TMC01_20170704042819.csv" "D:\Quarantine" /s /y
DEL "D:\root\TMC01_20170704042819.csv"
```

Comment: What have you triied so far, where are you stuck? Please share your efforts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way would be to use PowerShell. This script generates the XCOPY and DEL commands. It also produces an equivalent PowerShell command. I am not quite sure what `XCOPY /S` would mean for copying a single file name.

```
PS C:\src\t> Get-Content .\scan001.ps1
$filelist = Get-Content .\scan001.txt |
    ForEach-Object { if ($_ -match '"Target file: (.*) \(.*') { $matches[1] } } |
    ForEach-Object {
        Write-Host "XCOPY `"$($matches[1])`" `"D:\Quarantine`" /S /Y"
        Write-Host "DEL `"$($matches[1])`""
        Write-Host "Move-Item `"$($matches[1])`" `"D:\Quarantine`" -Force"
    }
```

An example run shows the output.

```
PS C:\src\t> .\scan001.ps1
XCOPY "D:\root\TMC01_20170704042819.csv" "D:\Quarantine" /S /Y
DEL "D:\root\TMC01_20170704042819.csv"
Move-Item "D:\root\TMC01_20170704042819.csv" "D:\Quarantine" -Force
```

Comment: I finally got some time to spend on this. When attempting to run this script I receive the error below, I'm running the script from C:\src\t ans the script name is scan001.ps1 and the file to be scanned is called scan001.txt...

Comment: PS C:\Src\t> C:\Src\t\scan001.ps1
Get-Process : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '.\scan001.ps1'.
At C:\Src\t\scan001.ps1:1 char:1
+ PS Get-Content .\scan001.ps1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-Process], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetProcessCommand

Comment: @Sumo - There is no `Get-Process` in this script. The first line uses `Get-Content`.

Comment: The error message did not completely copy into the Comment window. I've uploaded an image to photobucket... http://s58.photobucket.com/user/barfly67barfly67/media/scan001_zpsjjmsghqx.jpg.html

Comment: @Sumo - The first line you have in the `scan001.ps1` file is the PS command prompt from which I showed the contents of the script. `PS` is  a PowerShell alias for `Get-Process`. It is taken from the UNIX/Linux `ps` command. Delete the first line that starts with `PS` and run again.

Comment: Cool, thanks very much. here is the code that I ended up with that works well. I had to remove a double quote from in front of ($_ -match '"Target file: (.*) target file to get the script working.

Comment: $filelist = Get-Content .\scan001.txt |
    ForEach-Object { if ($_ -match 'Target file: (.*) \(.*') { $matches[1] } } |
    ForEach-Object {
        Write-Host "Move-Item `"$($matches[1])`" `"D:\Quarantine`" -Force"
        Move-Item $($matches[1]) D:\Quarantine -Force
    }

Answer (score 0):

This following script will do that for you. Remove the `echo` in front of the `XCOPY` if it's fine for you. Note it's batch script which expects the file from which you want to extract the names from as argument.

Usage: `script.bat filelist.txt`

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

if [%1] == [] (
   echo Usage %0 ^<filename^>
   goto eof
)

set "filelist=%1"

for /F "delims=( tokens=1" %%A in (%filelist%) do (
   set "filename=%%A"

   rem remove "Target file: " from beginning
   set "find=*Target file: "
   call set filename=%%filename:!find!=%%
   rem after: "D:\root\TMC01_20170704042819.csv "

   rem remove space at the end
   set "filename=!filename:~0,-1!"

   echo xcopy "!filename!" "D:\Quarantine" /s /y
   echo DEL "!filename!"
)

:eof
```